# PHP file executing despite using 'ForceType image/jpeg' in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

To prevent any PHP files from executing if uploaded to my image directory, I have created a `.htaccess` file solely containing `ForceType image/jpeg`, placed within this directory.

While this successfully causes `evil.txt` to be interpreted as an image file when opened by a browser, `evil.php` executes just fine (it echoes text to the browser). I have even tried directly targeting it:

```
<FilesMatch "evil.php">
    ForceType image/jpeg
</FilesMatch>
```

But this doesn't work either.

Comment: Why not redirect such requests to a 404 page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two completely unrelated things. [`ForceType`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#forcetype) is for the client, not the web server. The thing that's interpreting the PHP is your apache httpd web server. The way it knows to interpret a file as PHP or not is based on your [`FilesMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch) directive containing a [`SetHandler`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#sethandler) which lets httpd know to let these files go to `mod_php`. These two things are completely unrelated to each other.

In other words, you're probably thinking (very cleverly) that you're doing something that's going to make your apache httpd configuration *more* safe. I assure you that you aren't. Files that don't end in `.php` won't go through php in that configuration scenario. And since you control what files are named in your webroot, this should not be a concern. Simply don't allow the user to control the naming of files on your server. It's that simple